# Break Ranking Ties with multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates, unique, ranking

I'm trying to rank on multiple criteria `values` and `window` but do not want ties within ranks.

The formula i have satisfies the multiple criteria but not tie breaking.

```
=COUNTIF($H$5:$H$105412<"&H89)+COUNTIFS($H$5:$H$105412,H89,$E$5:$E$105412,"<"&E89)+1
```

[image]

I'd like for the highlighted `values` to be unique and break ties.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Add one more column beside it, say column J and write this formula in Cell

```
J6=COUNTIFS($H$5:$H6,$H6,$E$5:$E6,$E6,$I$5:$I6,$I6)
```

Now drag this formula down till the end of your sheet.
This will record the instances in which the combination of ranks occur in ascending order. 
Just filter out all values where the value in column J is **1**. This will be the single non-duplicate entry.

Comment: Thanks @harinp715 but I was hoping to not filter. rather have the ranking ignore duplicates. i.e. instead of [1,2,2,3,3] it gives [1,2,3,4,5]

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me. it ranks the `value` against the range while considering the condition of `windows` as a criteria and also break ties when a duplicate occurs within the same condition or `window`

```
=RANK(E5,INDEX(E$5:E$1000,MATCH($H5,$H$5:$H$1000,0)):INDEX(E$5:E$1000,MATCH($H5,$H$5:$H$1000,0)+COUNTIF($H$5:$H$1000,$H5)-1),1)+COUNTIFS($H$5:$H5,$H5,$E$5:$E5,$E5)-1
```